# myapps.microsoft.com infinite loop after removing self from Azure AD directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I went to https://myapps.microsoft.com in an attempt to finally remove old Azure AD Domains from my account. I went to the organization's tab and left an Azure AD Domain, and now `myapps.microsoft.com` just keeps infinite looping forever, reloading the page endlessly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What is your browser? Change another one to have a try.

Comment: I tired both Edge and Chrome, and no luck.